# So how are you supposed to point a question at a different Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion

Saw this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247817/what-is-the-function-of-voltage-divider-in-this-circuit-below

Added a note that it belonged in electronics.stackexchange.com, and then flagged it for moderator attention, saying: "Belongs on electronics.stackexchange.com"

The flag was rejected with: "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"

Note that electronics isn't one of the sites one can indicate with an "Off Topic" closing code.

So, how should this have been handled?

Answer (score 5):

While that question is certainly more *on-topic* for Electronics.SE, its total crap, and not worth migrating.

We should only be migrating (and flagging to migrate) **high-quality** questions that are posted on the wrong site. Otherwise it will just get closed on the other site, rejecting the migration, and we gave that community a bunch of work for nothing.

Comment: So is the solution to improve it per the other site's standards and then flag it for migration?

Comment: @tepples If you feel you can improve it, then sure. Otherwise, just VTC and vote to delete.