# Are questions tagged [stm32] on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952229/how-to-display-on-lcd-16x2-using-stm32f103c8-without-using-libraries-in-keil) in the review queue and I tried to flag it as off-topic.

Number 1: I mentioned that question belongs on another site. The site I had in mind was [electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) but it is not an option when flagging.

Number 2: I found a similar [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285172/so-how-are-you-supposed-to-point-a-question-at-a-different-stack-exchange-site) on meta which mentions about low quality posts.

Number 3: In 2018 alone, there are more than 400+ questions with the [stm32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stm32) tag, a few questions with more than 8k views. There is a total of 1661 questions with this tag.

Are these questions really on-topic? Where do the micro-controller program questions go?

Comment: If they involve code (writing code for microcontrollers seems to be a a job people can have) I see no reason why they couldn't be on-topic. The example question is unclear if not too broad and I wouldn't dare to redirect that question to EE.se. Let's handle the mess here and not dump it on another site.

Comment: A great many of such questions are off-topic/too broad because the problems cannot be effectively solved without access to the OP's hardware and environment.  I know it's not very satisfactory overall, but no matter where such questions are posted, it's unlikely that much useful help can be given without a very long exchange that amounts to remote hardware and software debugging by exchanging text messages.  That is hugely unproductive and ineffective:(

Comment: I agree with @MartinJames on this. The 'question in question' is a low quality post and has to be cleaned up. I will flag it appropriately. But there are questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875873/stm32f4-uart-hal-driver) which have received more than 50k views but clearly belong in EE.se Is the tag prompting more people to post on stackoverflow instead of EE?

Comment: I can, and often do, give some advice in a comment, (eg. 'scope the output and measure the real bit rate, then fix your clock generator init so it works'), but it's rare that I can cough up an actual answer that would be useful to future SO users/visitors.

Comment: My belief is people at EE are more qualified to answer these than at SO. Correct me if I am wrong. There are few like @MartinJames and myself who worked both on hardware and programming in general.

Comment: @nightgaunt the best place to post, for many questions, is the controller vendor support blogs.

Comment: @nightgaunt looking at your example question, it's not suitable for SO, or EE or vendor blog.  It belongs in the 'hopeless' category.  No code for SO except reference to keil libs, and no wiring diagram.for EE.  Let's face it - we don't even know if the OP's display has power:(   EE would not thank us for migrating that!

Comment: So, you were 100% right when you flagged it for closure:)  It's now on hold, and the rumbaba will deal with it eventually:

Comment: In embedded it is most important to know the architecture, as much as it's relevant to know if it's Windows, MacOS or Linux, etc. for a question asking about OS-specific details. Nevertheless, the tag alone is insufficient, so I'm not sure the tag itself makes much sense (there eare also more specific stm32 tags, but I prefer this in theu question, simply because of the plethora (most likely far over 100 common now) of different MCUs. MCU questions are imo borderline and often problematic, but nevertheless they are programming-related and some are on-topic. This one could be, but lacks info

Comment: Btw.: There are over 750k [tag:html] questions. It is not even a programming language, so I wonder if they are on-topic here. [tag:vhdl] has over 4k questions, [tag:pdf] over 35000. [tag:linux] >165k. I don't see what your problem is with the stm32 tag or [tag:embedded] itself.

Comment: To be clear: I think we could get rid of these MCU-specific tags and require this information provided (along with more) in the text. But it's not about such questions themslves being off-topic per-se.

Comment: @Olaf good point about html.  It's obviously off-topic because hypertext links, eg. 'idownvotedbecau.se/' are continually flagged, so we should surely burninate html:)

Comment: @MartinJames That would be [tag:http] (>48k questions)

Comment: Again, my belief is that the people at EE are more qualified to answer these than at SO. Correct me if I am wrong. Hence the question Where do the micro-controller program questions go.

Comment: Well, the OP's would have to make a judgement based on their own question details, and the site policies for SO, EE etc, to decide which SE site to post on, or to not post on SE at all.  SO should not be used by OP's as a site search and migration service - the OP needs to make the decision.

Comment: @nightgaunt: Repeating the statement from your question does not change it. There are embedded programming questions which are on-topic, or at least could be if phrased properly. There is no need to judge them differently from any other programming questions, so there is also no need to make them artificially off-topic. And I don't understand what your particular problem with [tag:stm32] is, what about [tag:avr], [tag:mips], [tag:arm]…? it's just the same as [tag:linux] or [tag:windows]: It specifies the platform. Like the other two tags, it can be sufficient or require additional information.

Comment: @Olaf That makes sense. I have been answering questions related to [tag:gatt] and [tag:bluetooth] once upon a time. There's no point getting itchy just because a question was low quality. As Martin mentioned, better to leave it to OP's judgement

Comment: On another note: The other question you link in a comment is also off-topic for a normal reason which applies to all questions here: POB, maybe too broad. Views are a nonsense measure, as e.g. a lot of curators on SO check every question in "their" tags, creating views. The fact querstions haven't been closed properly is a non-sequitur the whole area is off-topic. (And no, it's not just OP's jugement whether a question is on-topic either. We have enough meta about folks whining their obviously off-topic question should be handled here)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, microcontroller programming is perfectly on-topic both on SO and on EE. The two sites have overlapping topic scopes here. Similarly, HDL programming is also on-topic on both sites.

Though if you suspect that the problem could be either software- or hardware-related, it is always better to ask on EE, since the question would still be on-topic in case of hardware problems.

If asking microcontroller programming questions on SO, use the following tags:

- MCU family, such as [stm32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stm32), [pic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pic), [atmega](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atmega).
- CPU core, such as [cortex-m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortex-m). (Necessary when asking about assembly, performance etc.)
- The [embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded) tag, to indicate that it is an embedded systems question and not PC/desktop.
- Compiler tags, when relevant.

*Do not* use manufacturer company name tags such as [microchip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microchip), [st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/st) etc. These are to be regarded as obsolete and the site-wide policy is not to use company name tags.

Comment: Great answer. Could you also put the link to the policy in your answer?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker It's as per the Apple and Microsoft tag burninations. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333833/i-want-my-overcooked-apple-pie

Comment: That may be a case of taking a specific case (a company with lots of popular product lines) and generalizing it too far. Some companies (I’m thinking specifically of Nordic semiconductor, but there are others), where the “popular” product is synonymous with the company itself and therefore that treatment wouldn’t necessarily apply. For instance, see Shog’s comment under that answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker We also burned [IBM](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348131/watson-wants-to-get-rid-of-ibm), [HTC](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351225/should-we-burninate-the-htc-tag), [Embarcadero](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377488/the-embarcadero-tag-has-been-burninated) etc etc. There's clearly a policy in place, but it might not have been written down explicitly somewhere.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker In case of Nordic semi, you should tag the question nrf-something after the _product_. Company names for semiconductor companies are particularly troublesome since they constantly merge, split and change names. We have for example 522 questions tagged Atmel, but there is no company called Atmel any longer and the tag turned completely useless and obsolete. We have the Motorola tag which is problematic, because it is used both for smart phones and for old CPUs. Etc etc.

Comment: I think it may have gotten lost in translation, and for any confusion caused I apologize. We have burned company tags in the past, but that doesn’t equate to always burning company tags. The tag should be burned if it can cause confusion among product lines (Motorola is a great example). Otherwise, don’t worry about it.